# Put leaflet.locate (blue dot) above all other layers

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis

I'm using leaflet.locate along with leaflet routing machine to show my location along a route. My problem is that when I recreate the route the blue location dot is below the route line generated by leaflet routing machine. How do I ensure the location dot is above the route layer?

The code below does not seem to work.

```
var myLocationControl = L.control.locate({follow: true, stopFollowingOnDrag: true, keepCurrentZoomLevel: true,
showPopup: true, remainActive: true,
strings: {
    title: "Track Location",
    metersUnit: "meters",
    feetUnit: "feet"
    outsideMapBoundsMsg: "You seem located outside the boundaries of the map" // default message for onLocationOutsideMapBounds
}, locateOptions: {enableHighAccuracy: true}}).addTo(map);

//Put on top
myLocationControl.setZIndexOffset(2000);
```

I have also tried this:

```
myLocationControl._circle.bringToFront();
myLocationControl._marker.bringToFront();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Leaflet.Locate` uses `L.Path` to draw circles, which in turn uses SVG elements. There are no `z-index` property for SVG elements, so, you can't use methods like `setZIndex()` or `setZIndexOffset()`.

The only thing I can suggest is to use `L.Path.bringToFront()` method after you add all the route layers. Here is an example:

```js
var locate = L.control.locate();

//later, after you add all the layers
locate._circle.bringToFront();
locate._marker.bringToFront();
```

Or you can call `bringToBack()` for every added route.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time but this didn't work for me.

Comment: You implemented this approach and it didn't work or you just can't control geometry additions?

Comment: I implemented your recommendation and it didn't bring the leaflet.locate dot to the foreground

Comment: Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/parshin/fxywmrc1/ First, press locate icon to show location. Then press "Add polygon" button to add new polygon. Location circles still will be above the polygon.